# Sum of 5 natural numbers while displaying the equations, like showing 0+1=1 and 1+2=3 when running the program

Tags: c#, console-application

Running the program shows 1+1=1 and 2+3=3, instead of 0+1=1 and 1+2=3. Tried adding another variable named "ans" for the "n + sum" equation after replacing "sum" at the left side of the equal sign and the "+sum" part at "(""+n+" + "+sum+" = "+sum)", but it just shows 1+0=1 and 2+0=2 when running.

```
int n = 1, sum = 0;
while (n <= 5)
{
    sum = n + sum;
    Console.WriteLine(""+n+" + "+sum+" = "+sum);
    n++;
}
```

Comment: So, add `sum=ans` at the end?

Comment: It's not clear to me what specifically you're asking.  Are you expecting the `sum` variable to have two different values at the same time?  When you step through this code in a debugger, which specific operation isn't doing what you expect?  What are the values used in that operation?  What is the result?  What result was expected?  And, most importantly, *why* was that result expected?

Comment: Remove `sum = n + sum` and replace last `sum` in console write with `(sum = n + sum)`... asking such question will not learn you any programming language because even if you follow the answer you will not understand why it's working

Comment: ... Or just store last sum before modification somewhere and then use it... Seems like you have problem with understanding of variable concept

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to calculate and display a running sum from 1 to 5. However, there's a small issue in your code. You're updating sum before displaying the equation, which causes it to be incorrect. Here's the corrected code:

```
int n = 1, sum = 0;
while (n <= 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n + " + " + sum + " = " + (n + sum));
    sum = n + sum; // Update sum after displaying the equation
    n++;
}
```

With this code, you'll get the expected output:

```
1 + 0 = 1
2 + 1 = 3
3 + 3 = 6
4 + 6 = 10
5 + 10 = 15
```

Now, sum is updated after displaying the equation, ensuring that it correctly accumulates the sum of the numbers.